# Creating a database in MariaDB-10.2.9 using the schema that comes with Barnyard2

Tags: mysql

I used phpMyAdmin to create the tables in the Snort database but the creation of two of the tables fails with the seemingly ubiquitous error 1064.  The schema entries are as follows -

```
  CREATE TABLE reference(ref_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                         ref_system_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                         ref_tag TEXT NOT NULL,
                         PRIMARY KEY(ref_id));

  CREATE TABLE reference_system(ref_system_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
                                AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                ref_system_name VARCHAR(20),
                                PRIMARY KEY(ref_system_id));
```

The first CREATE statement gives the error -

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ref_system_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ref_tag ' at line 2
```

and the second create statement gives -

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ref_system_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ' at line 1
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with these two CREATE statements when all of the others in the schema work fine.  Can anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the pulled git, i have the same issue, looking at linuxquestions: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/barnyard2-setup-4175616443/

It seems to be working if you directly paste the output of the file from GIT: https://github.com/firnsy/barnyard2/blob/master/schemas/create_mysql

Tried to manually add lines 53 and 58 and that seemed to work for me.

EDIT:
after further searching it seems that the DOC we are using  from SNORT is referring to a forked version of barnyard2 by binf:
https://github.com/binf/barnyard2/tree/bug-fix-release
When looking at the git from the original dev firnsy we see he added a comment to the file:
https://github.com/firnsy/barnyard2/tree/master/schemas

EDIT2:
Ahw man, now we get errors in Barnyard when trying to run it:

```
[SystemPullDataStore()]: Failed exeuting query [SELECT ref_system_id, ref_system_name FROM reference_system;] , will retry
```

When trying it Mariadb:

```
MariaDB [snort]> select ref_system_id, ref_system_name from reference_system;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ref_system_id, ref_system_name from reference_system' at line 1
```

When trying with backticks:

```
MariaDB [snort]> select `ref_system_id`, ref_system_name from 
reference_system;
+---------------+-----------------+
| ref_system_id | ref_system_name |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             1 | Manually_Added  |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

seems to be an issue with compilation:
https://github.com/firnsy/barnyard2/issues/178

I am dropping mariadb and going to use postgreSQl. hopefully with a little more luck there.